# How to calculate percentage of buyers who bought over 1k EUR from two columns in Power BI? Which DAX Formula?

Tags: powerbi, dax, formula, powerbi-desktop

I have to separate sheets imported from two separate Excel sheets in Power BI Desktop which contain different customers from different countries that have spent sums between 50 and 50,000 EUR on different products.
I would like to find out the percentage of customers that bought products worth over 1k EUR from each column and also showcase their country of origin. Added images below

**Table 1**

[image]

**Table 2**

[image]

Should I merge the tables or ?

So far, I tried multiple formulas but none of them seemed to work, the majority of them I found on Microsoft.Community.

Comment: You can merge two tables. Else You can find individual values and then add them and then find the percentage. In both scenarios ultimately create measures using COUNT > 1k. and then divide the count by the total records (another measure) in the merged or 2 tables.

Comment: BTW this has nothing to do with Excel.

Comment: Update your question with the data in markdown table format so that we copy and paste. Also add which formulas you have used. If the two sheets have the same columns then I suspect you want to `Append` the two tables (not `Merge`).